# Networking stop working after suspend

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend

I am new to the Linux environment in general. So please, bear with me.

I am currently running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on Asus Vivobook pro 15 OLED with Intel core i5-11300H, Nvidia GTX 1650 MAX-Q, and the mt7921e network adapter.
System information:

```
Linux 5.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have recently dual-booted Ubuntu with Windows 10 and everything is just working fine in both systems. The issue occurs only after I wake up my laptop from suspend. Then weird behavior starts to show.
First, networking stops working altogether. Wifi icon in the top bar gets grayed out with no label beside it (I will include screenshots if needed). Also in the Network settings tab, I get an error saying "something went wrong".
Second, the whole system starts acting weird. For example, any `sudo` terminal command freezes the terminal and gets listed with `S+` status (if I remember correctly) in the `ps aux` output, they never get executed and they are unkillable (since killing them needs `sudo` command as well).
Also, any application that I try to open takes ages to run, be it the settings or firefox, etc. And sometimes they don't get to launch at all.
Finally, if I try to reboot or shutdown the system, it gets stuck with an error similar to this
`Waiting for stop job (1 of 3) NetWorkManager ...`
`Waiting for stop job (2 of 3) WPA_supplicant ...`
The only way that worked for me is to force shutdown using the physical power button, booting Ubuntu in recovery mode, normally shutting down the system after I get to the desktop screen, and then booting the system normally. After that everything goes back to normal.

Here is the output that I got from running the Logs GUI Gnome application in the "important" section:

```
 2:00:18 AM NetworkManager: <error> [1675206018.9695] device (wlo1): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: Timeout was reached
 2:00:15 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: driver own failed
 2:00:15 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: driver own failed
 2:00:13 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: Message 00000046 (seq 6) timeout
 2:00:08 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: chip reset
 2:00:08 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: driver own failed
 2:00:07 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
 2:00:07 AM kernel: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_resume+0x0/0x100 returns -5
 2:00:07 AM kernel: mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
 1:34:28 AM kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-ASUE120B:00: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (16/60416)
 1:34:28 AM gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
 1:34:27 AM gnome-session-b: GLib-CRITICAL: g_hash_table_foreach_remove_or_steal: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
 1:34:25 AM systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
 1:34:19 AM gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
 1:34:12 AM gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
 1:34:11 AM wpa_supplicant: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
 1:34:09 AM canonical-livep: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/********/updates" failed, retrying in 30s.
 1:34:08 AM kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
 1:34:08 AM thermald: Unsupported conditions are present
 1:34:07 AM bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Jan 31 10:34:19 PM kernel: mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: Firmware init done
Jan 31 10:34:19 PM kernel: 
Jan 31 10:34:19 PM kernel: mt7921e 0000:2e:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
Jan 31 10:34:18 PM kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.EC0.SEN4._AC0 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
Jan 31 10:34:18 PM kernel: pci 0000:00:07.0: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
```

I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu multiple times and that didn't work.
So, I replaced Ubuntu with Linux Mint at first, then with Pop_OS!. But even those two had the same issue. I looked up solutions all over the place. I even tried asking ChatGPT, which told me to upgrade the network card drivers. So I tried looking for that and I found this article https://miloserdov.org/?p=6899 that suggested updating the Linux kernel. But that did not work either.

Any help is appreciated. Tell me if there is any more information that I need to provide.

Comment: I have the exact same problem on a Lenovo P15 Gen2 with dual graphics. When I do prime-select intel it works fine. Something with the NVIDIA proprietary drivers messes things up. Did you find a solution? It is quite hard to debug.

Comment: @the_playerp In my case, even `prime-select intel` doesn't work. I have tried many things but nothing seems to work. Anyway, I have found a way to prevent the "weird behavior" I mentioned in the OP by simply stopping the `NetworkManager` service before suspending the laptop. Of course, you can't use the network with this, and starting the service again will bring back the "weird behavior". But at least the system won't bug out and I can shut it down normally with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking for a solution to this issue for quite some time now. But in the end, I got an easy solution to this bug. I found this bug report [mt7921e wifi fails to resume after suspend](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1975444) published by [David Soles](https://launchpad.net/%7Edavidsoles). One of the comments on this report suggested this:

> For those looking for a solution, I solved the problem on a Vivobook_ASUSLaptop K6501ZM_K6501ZM/K6501ZM, BIOS K6501ZM.204 by using Ubuntu 23.04 kernel 6.2.0-20-generic and set the mem_sleep_default kernel parameter to 'deep'

This comment was published by [gugaiz](https://launchpad.net/%7Egugaiz). I tried their solution on my Asus Vivobook Pro 15 K3500PH, and it worked perfectly after installing Ubuntu 23.04. I don't know whether this works on Ubuntu LTS 22.04 because I didn't try it before upgrading. But it's worth trying out if you are facing the same problem.